# getting error while building the code from github

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

Error:

```
error: index-pack died of signal 15
fatal: index-pack failed

at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2002)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1721)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:405)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:886)
... 11 more
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace inclusive the environment where you are running? What are the exact commands you've used to build and JDK version / Maven Version ?

Comment: Environment : VirtualBox

Comment: I build from GUI of jenkins. Maven Version:- 3.0.5 JDK Version: 1.8.0_171. Issue has been resolved, it was due to low memory of VM.

Comment: Really using such an old Maven version? Ok..